# C# Deserialize JSON to any type method

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

so i have this method (the second block of code)
that convert any json to c sharp object it works good but

what i want to do his to 
be able to tell the method which type of object she need to cast to

```
//not real code

public static object JSONToObj(string i_json, typeof(Home)) //will return an Home object

//not real code

//real code

public static object JSONToObj(string i_json)
{
     serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     object io_obj = serializer.Deserialize<object>(i_json);

     return io_obj;
}

//real code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static T JSONToObj<T>(string i_json)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    T io_obj = serializer.Deserialize<T>(i_json);

    return io_obj;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
Home h = JSONToObj<Home>(json);
```

Comment: and how should i call this method ?

Comment: @dotnetom You need to add a constraint `where T : new()` for the type to be deserializable

Comment: Updated types. You can't return an `object` for type `T`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov If that were the case, wouldn't the `Deserialize` method have that same constraint? But it doesn't: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - If Deserialize had new() restriction, then the same restriction would be required here

Comment: @weston - Try deserializing a class which doesn't have a parameterless  constructor. You'll get a `MethodMissingException` from the `JavaScriptSerializer`

Comment: @dotnetom It definitely is required. Try yourself and see.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yeah a runtime exception. It compiles and runs without it, so you don't **need** to add it "for the type to be deserializable". It's a sensible idea though, why it's not a constraint on `Deserialize` I don't know.

Comment: @weston I did not say that you need it for your code to **compile**, i said you need it to guarantee that any type you pass to the method can be a candidate to deserialization given a proper JSON

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov You said "you need to add a constraint" and "It definitely is required". Both of which are untrue. You didn't however say what you just said now which is correct.

Comment: @weston My intent was the need to add it so the code flow will be valid, i wasn't talking about compilation. I should of wrote "should" instead of "need". About the "definitely required", again that was regarding correct behavior and not compilation. Anyway, you get the point.